# Unable to install SQL Server 2022 on ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sql

I am having trouble on installing SQL server 2022 Express...

```
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server Hit:1
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease          
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease       
Hit:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease           
Hit:4 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease   
Hit:5 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease 
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022
focal InRelease Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod
focal InRelease Reading package lists... Done Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information...
Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
resolve the situation:
 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mssql-server :
Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct
problems, you have held broken packages.
```

... i tried to reinstall the packages but nothing changes..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be the final part of the output:

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

You can try some of these steps: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Not an answer a comment.

Comment: You are right, but I'm too low on rep to comment or flag as duplicate, so this is the second best thing I could do to help

Comment: Except a mod will remove it so no it does not help to try and side step the rules.

Answer (score 1):

`libldap-2.4-2` is not installable in Ubuntu 22.10 because it was removed from the Ubuntu repositories after Ubuntu 20.04.

The instructions you are following are obsolete. Notify whomever you got those instructions from that they need to update it.

Alternately, you can install Ubuntu 20.04. The package is available in that release.